# Are there success stories of OpenSource projects using Agile/Scrum methodologies?

Tags: open-source, agile, scrum

Most succesful , and large open source projects seem to follow the Benevolent Dictator style organization. But I was wondering if there are any success stories with agile development in Open source. When refering to Open source I mean large net-community driven development, not established teams doing Open source under the same roof.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is based on a misunderstanding.  If you have a look at the [Agile Manifesto](http://agilemanifesto.org/principles.html), most open-source projects *are* "agile".

Few if any open source projects follow the exact practices of XP or SCRUM (etc), but then the environment is different.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I'm curious about, philosophically Agile and OpenSource go together, but Agile is not community based and OSource lacks "stakeholders" of the Scrum type, so the method needs tweaking, and that tweaking is what I'm looking for.

Comment: You tell me what this "Agile" is that you speak of, and I'll tell you how it fits.  It's not like there's a specific agile methodology; the manifesto seems to apply, but you have to think about what "business" and "stakeholder" mean in context.

Comment: @Robert Gould: how is Agile not community based?  All stakeholders are a community by definition.  Open Source usually means the developers ARE the stakeholders.  Can't get more agile than that?

Comment: @Robert, I think you may not have the question clear in your own mind.  Do you mean "I don't see how to fit specific agile method X into open source without changes?"  I agree that's tough.

Comment: Here here, Charlie!  I will spare you the details but I am studying Agile for my dissertation so many people confuse the term for SCRUM!

Answer (score 2):

I haven't really looked at the code, but I know the "Fitnesse" project uses pretty strict Agile development practices.  In this case Bob Martin might be sort of a benevolent dictator who oversees the code, but they're using a lot of Agile practices like TDD, etc.

I'm not sure if they're using SCRUM specifically though.

http://fitnesse.org/